# Why are inputs for convolutional neural networks always squared images?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I have been doing deep learning with CNN for a while and I realize that the inputs for a model are always squared images.

I see that neither convolution operation or neural network architecture itself require such property.

So, what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

Because square images are pleasing to the eye. But there are applications on non-square images when domain requires it. For instance SVHN original dataset is an image of several digits, and hence rectangular images are used as input to convnet, as [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6082)

Answer (score 2):

From Suhas Pillai:

> The problem is not with convolutional layers, it's the fully connected
>   layers of the network ,which require fix number of neurons.For
>   example, take a small 3 layer network + softmax layer. If first 2
>   layers are convolutional + max pooling, assuming the dimensions are
>   same before and after convolution, and pooling reduces dim/2 ,which is
>   usually the case. For an image of 3*32*32(C,W,H)with 4 filters in the
>   first layer and 6 filters in the second layer ,the output after
>   convolutional + max pooling at the end of 2nd layer, will be 6*8*8
>   ,whereas for an image with 3*64*64, at the end of 2nd layer output
>   will be 6*16*16. Before doing fully connected,we stretch this as a
>   single vector( 6*8*8=384 neurons)and do a fully connected operation.
>   So, you cannot have different dimension fully connected layers for
>   different size images. One way to tackle this is using spatial pyramid
>   pooling, where you force the output of last convolutional layer to
>   pool it to a fixed number of bins(I.e neurons) such that fully
>   connected layer has same number of neurons. You can also check fully
>   convolutional networks, which can take non-square images.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to have squared images. I see two "reasons" for it:

- scaling: If images are scaled automatically from another aspect ratio (and landscape / portrait mode) this in average might introduce the least error
- publications / visualizations: square images are easy to display together